# Can't center title in ActionBar

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-actionbar, title

I need to center a title in ActionBar, so I've created custom ActionBar and function that sets custom title, but title is still not at the center.

```
class MainActivity: BaseActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        createCustomActionBar("Home")
    }

    fun createCustomActionBar(title: String){
        supportActionBar?.let {
            it.displayOptions = ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM

            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this@MainActivity)
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null)

            val titleActionBar: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.title)
            titleActionBar.text = title


            it.customView = view
        }
    }
}
```

**custom_action_bar.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Text"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter_semibold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**[Result I'm getting and where it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6qeW.png)**

Comment: I think you should do `android:gravity="center"` instead of `android:layout_gravity="center"` on `LinearLayout`

Comment: Give your containing layout a `match_parent` width so it fills the toolbar space (and so will the `TextView`). Hussain's right about using `gravity` on the layout instead (controls the position of all the views *inside* the container, which is what you're trying to do) - but you don't need it in this case since the `TextView` fills the container anyway (`match_parent` height and width)

Answer (score 0):

For your `LinearLayout`, you should use `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`. Otherwise the gravity cannot be applied correctly.

And as your `TextView` uses `match_parent` and has applied `android:gravity="center"`, the `android:layout_gravity="center"` can be removed.

So the final resource layout should look like this:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Text"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter_semibold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it'is also not working for some reason, title is not at the cetner but I solved this with adding this code in createCustomActionBar:

```
val params = ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                Gravity.CENTER
            )

            it.setCustomView(view, params)
```

I don't know why it works and how solve the problem only with XML